# X Theme header position changing

Tags: html, css

The mobile number break at mobile screen, and I need to repair that, but actually I can't find the css where I can make some code.
If I'm using DevTools I find the css what I want to change, look at below:

Where should I search this? The site is: http://fulorrgegesz.com/

```
.x-navbar .desktop .x-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 0;
    height: auto;
}
.x-navbar .desktop .x-nav > li ul {
    top: 32px;
}
nav.x-nav-wrap.desktop #menu-miltenyi-menu {
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
}
.c_header_top {
    text-align: right;
    margin: 10px 0 17px 0;
}
.c_header_top a {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.c_header_top a:first-child {
    margin: 0 25px 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgb(0,98,20);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1px 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

Comment: use mediaquerys

Comment: but where should i put the mediaquerys if i cant find the css?

Comment: you could put it in `<style></style>` and this has to be in the head

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no style for that particular `<a>` and it breaks by default if no available space is left for text.

Use same CSS as for first link, just change child index:

```
.c_header_top a:last-child {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you thank you so much! This works. I'm so grateful for your answer!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

this website is in WordPress. so follow the below steps to find the custom css file..
1. Open [wp-admin](http://fulorrgegesz.com/wp-admin) of your website and log in.
2. find the Appearance in Side Navigation of wp-admin and click on it.
3. the dropdown side down after clicking on Appearance.
4. Custom CSS should appear in sub navigation of Appearance, click on it.

[attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdU9J.png)